# Configuring intern.json file to map to all dependencies

Tags: javascript, dojo, cucumber, karma-runner, intern

I’m having a lot of issues grabbing dependent files into my intern/cucumber tests. Here’s some background, I really hope someone can help! I’m making a change from Karma/Intern/Dojo —> Cucumber/intern/Dojo and I really want to replicate the “karma.config” file to “intern.json”

Basically, I have existing tests that have been created with intern and Karma. The karma configuration file preloads all dependencies in patterns, and specifies a **basePath**  which all files are related to. I have a ton of dependencies, and I've been trying to manually map them in my intern.json file but there are so many, it seems like there could be an easier way? here are how my two files look:

```
//configuration, for unit testing, this is my karma.conf.js


module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../../../../../..',

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['intern'],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser, etc
    files: [

        { pattern: 'FC/WorkFolder/Views/**/*.*', included: false, served: true, watched: false },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

    htmlReporter: {
        outputFile: 'Tools/Karma/HRunitTestReport.html'
    }
});
```

So, main idea is  that all the files are relative to that specified basePath, so when its pulling all the dependencies from hundreds of files, it always gets resolved and finds the files. My intern.json file looks like this:

```
{
"loader": {
"script": "dojo",
"options": {
  "packages": [

    {
      "name": "features",
      "location": "features"
    },
    {
      "name": "HR",
      "location": "../../../../../../WorkFolder/Scripts/Vews"
    },
    {
      "name": "dojo",
      "location": "node_modules/dojo"
    },
```

..etc. I'm basically manually mapping them so that its not searched for within the same folder that intern.json is contained in. its been working so far. but there are too many dependencies and I don't want to map all of them

Any help on how basePath works for intern and how I can imitate it will be super helpful

Comment: What are you trying to load? I mean, if you're using the dojo loader to load modules, it will need to be configured at least at the package level. If you want to load a bunch of modules into the browser's global namespace, you might want to do something else.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Basically i'm testing an HR application that has several forms. So there's the actual form constructor, buttons, etc etc.. within the actual form file, it has even more dependencies loaded with the Dojo define function.. its basically endless. The issue is that it is reading in most of the files i specify in the intern.json file. but each file depends on several other files which depend on several others. with karma, a bunch of patterns were loaded in the browser. Not sure how to do this in an intern.json file

Comment: I think.. Everything would work fine if i could use this already created karma.conf.js file with my new frameworks instead of recreating it with intern.json. Do you have any ideas on how to do that? is that config file karma-specific?

Comment: Hmmm...I still don't quite get what's being loaded. I mean, is the application written using AMD modules? Assuming it is, you just need to tell the loader (dojo) where to find the top-level packages (like "features" and "HR" and "dojo"), and the loader will take care of finding and loading all the individual files within the package whenever something requests them.

Comment: Ah, from looking at the [Karma docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/files.html), it sounds like that `files` attribute can be used to load arbitrary assets. If you need to statically load JS files into the browser using script tags, you could use Intern's 'plugins' property. Seeing an example of what you would normally need to load to test a module would help.

Comment: hi @jason0x43! I noticed, after doing a ton of research, that you are involved in intern-cucumber integrations... So I have a question. I want to use the cucumber intern PLUGIN (nppm intern-cucumber). The issue is that, I am currently using intern as a **framework** and karma as the actual test runner. I don't have an intern.json file as all my files are loaded with karma.conf.js folder.. how can I use the intern-cucumber plugin?

Comment: You might be able to get somewhere by importing the cucumber interface from intern-cucumber directly (`require('intern-cucumber/interface/cucumber')`). In general, though, many/most plugins likely won't work when Intern isn't being used as the test runner because plugins typically operate by attaching to the active Intern test runner.

Comment: is there anyway I can get this https://github.com/rhpijnacker/intern3-cucumber/blob/master/lib/interfaces/cucumber.js to work again? from what I see its ac actual interface instead of a plugin

Comment: any reason why it doesnt work currently

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing? Have you tried the more current cucumber plugin at https://github.com/rhpijnacker/intern-cucumber?

Comment: im trying the current plugin but im having this issue now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313397/intern-cucumber-plugin-error-a-plugin-named-cucumber-has-not-been-registered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362329/define-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-run-my-intern-dojo-tests