# Intern-cucumber plugin error: A plugin named "cucumber" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, plugins, dojo, cucumber, intern

I'm trying to get the intern-cucumber plugin working. I get the following error:

```
Error: A plugin named "cucumber" has not been registered
  at Node.BaseExecutor.getPlugin @ src\lib\executors\Executor.ts:387:12
  @ tests\addition.js:6:29
  at runFactory @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1134:43
  at execModule @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1262:5
  at execModule @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1253:12
  @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1297:6
  at guardCheckComplete @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1277:5
  at checkComplete @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:1292:4
  at contextRequire @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:835:6
  at req @ node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:124:11
  @ src\loaders\dojo.ts:36:8
  at new Promise @ anonymous
  at Node._loader @ src\loaders\dojo.ts:29:13
  at Node._loadFunctionalSuites @ src\lib\executors\Node.ts:593:29
  @ src\lib\executors\Node.ts:882:24
  @ node_modules\@theintern\common\index.js:16:7174
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? My intern.json configuration file looks like:

```
{
  "loader": {
    "script": "dojo",
    "options": {
      "packages": [
        {
          "name": "features",
          "location": "features"
        },
        {
          "name": "models",
          "location": "models"
        },
        {
          "name": "dojo", 
          "location":  "node_modules/dojo"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "functionalSuites": "tests/**.js",
  "environments": [ "chrome" ],
  "browser": {
    "plugins": [
      "node_modules/intern-cucumber/browser/plugin.js"
    ]
  },
  "node": {
    "plugins": "node_modules/intern-cucumber/plugin.js"
  }

}
```

And my test file, where the error is happening, addition.js looks like:

```
define([
    'models/calculator',
    'dojo/text!features/addition.feature'
], function (calculator, featureSrc) {

    const cucumber = intern.getPlugin('cucumber');
    const assert = intern.getPlugin('chai').assert; 

    cucumber.registerCucumber('Calculator addition', featureSrc, function () {

        cucumber.Given('the calculator is cleared', function () {

        });

        cucumber.When(/^I add (\d+) and (\d+)$/, function (x, y) {
            var calc = new Calculator(x, y)

        })

        cucumber.Then(/^the result should be (\d+)$/, function (z) {
            var result = calc.sum();
            assert.equal(z,result,'Expected result to be: ' + z)
        })
    }

    )
}

)
```

Does anyone have ANY idea how to solve this? No idea why the plugin wouldn't work, is there something wrong with my intern.json file??

Answer (score 1):

The code is calling `intern.getPlugin('cucumber')`. It should actually be calling `intern.getPlugin('interface.cucumber')` or `intern.getInterface('cucumber')` (the former is preferred).

Intern has an API specifically for registering and retrieving interfaces (`registerInterface` and `getInterface`). However, it's just a thin wrapper around the general plugin API (`registerPlugin` and `getPlugin`) that adds `interface.` to the plugin name. The interface API will likely be removed in the future in favor of just having the single plugin API.